# Alinhar tabela em latex?

Tags: latex

Olá estou tentando alinhar essa tabela em uma pagina só porém não estou conseguindo alguém tem alguma dica que possa me ajudar?

```
    \documentclass{article}
% REFERÊNCIAS------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[%
    alf,
    abnt-emphasize=bf,
    bibjustif,
    recuo=0cm,
    abnt-url-package=url,       % Utiliza o pacote url
    abnt-refinfo=yes,           % Utiliza o estilo bibliográfico abnt-refinfo
    abnt-etal-cite=3,
    abnt-etal-list=3,
    abnt-thesis-year=final
]{abntex2cite}                  % Configura as citações bibliográficas conforme a norma ABNT

% PACOTES----------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                 % Codificação do documento
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                    % Seleção de código de fonte
\usepackage{booktabs}                                       % Réguas horizontais em tabelas
\usepackage{color, colortbl}                                % Controle das cores
\usepackage{float}                                          % Necessário para tabelas/figuras em ambiente multi-colunas
\usepackage{graphicx}                                       % Inclusão de gráficos e figuras
\usepackage{icomma}                                         % Uso de vírgulas em expressões matemáticas
\usepackage{indentfirst}                                    % Indenta o primeiro parágrafo de cada seção
\usepackage{microtype}                                      % Melhora a justificação do documento
\usepackage{multirow, array}                                % Permite tabelas com múltiplas linhas e colunas
\usepackage{subeqnarray}                                    % Permite subnumeração de equações
\usepackage{lastpage}                                       % Para encontrar última página do documento
\usepackage{verbatim}                                       % Permite apresentar texto tal como escrito no documento, ainda que sejam comandos Latex
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath}                     % Fontes e símbolos matemáticos
\usepackage[algoruled, portuguese]{algorithm2e}             % Permite escrever algoritmos em português
%\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}                                % Usa a fonte Helvetica
\usepackage{times}                                          % Usa a fonte Times
%\usepackage{palatino}                                      % Usa a fonte Palatino
%\usepackage{lmodern}                                       % Usa a fonte Latin Modern
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}                               % Mantém as notas de rodapé sempre na mesma posição
\usepackage{ae, aecompl}                                    % Fontes de alta qualidade
\usepackage{latexsym}                                       % Símbolos matemáticos
\usepackage{lscape}                                         % Permite páginas em modo "paisagem"
%\usepackage{picinpar}                                      % Dispor imagens em parágrafos
%\usepackage{scalefnt}                                      % Permite redimensionar tamanho da fonte
%\usepackage{subfig}                                        % Posicionamento de figuras
%\usepackage{upgreek}                                       % Fonte letras gregas
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption,multicol,booktabs,array}
% Redefine a fonte para uma fonte similar a Arial (fonte Helvetica)
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\title{tabela}
\author{matheusmachadoufsc }
\date{May 2017}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
    % \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
    % If you use beamer only pass "xcolor=table" option, i.e. \documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
    \begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    {\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
    \begin{tabular}{llllll}
    \rowcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} 
    \textbf{Aplicação}                                                                               & \textbf{O que é}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    & \textbf{Como}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        & \textbf{Onde}                                                                                                                           & \textbf{Pra quem}                                                                                                                                            & \textbf{Objetivo}                                                                                                                                                                                                                      \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{}}                                           & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Cartazes com etiqueta NFC embutidas, com informações armazenadas.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Espalhando os cartazes com a etiqueta, em diversos lugares da biblioteca. Os usuários necessitam apenas possuir um celular com NFC, e aproximar do cartaz, dessa forma, consegue realizar o download do livro.}                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Biblioteca virtual\\ Na\\ Áustria\end{tabular}}                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Usuários que preferem ter o livro em seus Smartphone e/ou quando o livro não está disponível}                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Realizar downloads de  livros}                                                                                                                                                             \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Smart Posters}}                              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Projeto com fim Educativo, que auxiliar jovens em obter conhecimentos sobre a sua região.}                                                                                                                                                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Foram espalhados pela cidade etiquetas NFC que contêm informações referente ao pontos que foi inserida. Com a aproximação do dispositivo móvel, consegue ler a etiqueta e receber as informações na tela do celular.}                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Finlândia\\ em Oulu\end{tabular}}                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Sociedade}                                                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Ajudar jovens a obter informações \\ sobre rotina, habilidades e conhecimentos histórico/cultural sobre a sua região e desenvolver gestão de vida\end{tabular}} \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}}                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Um folheto de supermercado, onde cada produto está inserido uma etiqueta NFC.}                                                                                                                                                                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Etiquetas embutidas no folheto, através do aplicativo lê-se as etiquetas apenas aproximando o dispositivo ao produto desejado e os pedidos são enviados para um sistema,do supermercado, na qual realiza a entrega das compras no mesmo dia.}                            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Finlândia\\ em Oulu\end{tabular}}                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Usuários que\\ frequentam\\ Supermercados\end{tabular}}                               & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Realizar compras utilizando o dispositivo móvel que possui NFC sem sair do imóvel.}                                                                                                        \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{B6B1B1}}                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Sistema de pagamentos da Google que permite ao usuário utilizar seu dispositivo móvel que contenha a tecnologia NFC como um cartão de crédito. Ao invés de carregar diversos\\ cartões o sistema permite ativar os cartões em seu dispositivo.\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Apenas aproximando seu smartphone do leitor NFC instalado nas máquinas de cartões ou de um terminal.}                                                                                                                                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Google Wallet}                                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Para pessoas que querem praticidade\\ na hora de realizar pagamentos.\end{tabular}}   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Realizar transações através do smartphone.}                                                                                                                                                \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{B6B1B1}\textbf{Pagamento}}                                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Pulseiras de pagamentos que possuem a Tecnologia NFC integrada.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}A pulseira funciona como um cartão pré-pago, assim, o usuário carrega a pulseira com uma quantidade de saldo via cartão de débito e aproxima da plataforma de pagamento.}                                                                                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Empresa\\ Valid\end{tabular}}                                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Para pessoas que querem praticidade\\ na hora de realizar pagamentos.\end{tabular}}   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Realizar pagamentos utilizando a pulseira.}                                                                                                                                                \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{B6B1B1}}                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Sistema de pagamento usando o dispositivo móvel.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Para utilizar necessita possuir o dispositivo com NFC, instalar o aplicativo, cadastrar o cartão e reconhecer a impressão digital.}                                                                                                                                      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Samsung\\ Pay\end{tabular}}                                      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Para pessoas que querem praticidade na\\ hora de realizar\\ pagamentos.\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Realizar pagamentos utilizando o smartphone.}                                                                                                                                              \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Jogos}}                                      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Cartão que possui a tecnologia NFC acoplada para desbloqueio ou visualizar informações na tela\\ dispositivo.\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Aproximando o cartão que é disponibilizado pela empresa ao celular com NFC.}                                                                                                                                                                                             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Nokia}                                                                                      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Usuários de dispositivos da\\ Nokia que possuem os jogos instalados.\end{tabular}}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Desbloquear níveis de jogos.}                                                                                                                                                              \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}}                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Pulseiras com a tecnologia NFC integrada para iniciar jogos eletrônicos, capturar fotos e vídeos do usuário.}                                                                                                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}A pulseira possui identificação única e é codificada. No parque estão espalhados 25 leitores,  para a criança jogar necessita aproximar a pulseira do leitor NFC que coleta as informações contida na pulseira e encaminha para o sistema do parque.}                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Mongo Park em Israel}                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Para crianças}                                                                                                   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Entreter as crianças enquanto os pais realizam suas compras, com diversos jogos}                                                                                                           \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{B6B1B1}\textbf{Alimentador Inteligente}}                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Alimentador para animais de estimação, na qual fornece ração com a quantidade determinada e,monitora a quantidade de água ingerida avisando o dono sobre essa ação.}                                                                                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}O equipamento possui duasantenas RFID, implantadas uma no bebedouro e outra no comedouro, através das antenasconsegue a comunicação com a tag NFC que deve está pendurada no pescoço do animal, assim, o alimentador Consegue funcionar.}                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Colégio SESI deCianorte no Paraná}                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Para pessoas que possuem algum animal de estimação.}                                                             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Facilitar a vida de pessoas que possuem algum animal de estimação, gerando menores preocupações sobre a saúde do animal.}                                                                  \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Aluguel de Bicicletas}}                      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Sistema de aluguel para bicicletas em terminais distribuídos pela cidade.}                                                                                                                                                                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Deverá possuir um smartphone que contenha a tecnologia NFC e o aplicativo disponibilizado pela empresa, assim, os ciclistas podem efetuar login no sistema pelo dispositivo, inserindo o PIN em uma estação e se o cliente for autorizado é Liberado o uso da bicicleta} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Nextbike, empresa que oferece serviços para aluguel de bicicletas em Leipzig, na Alemanha.} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Usuários de bicicletas Alugadas.}                                                                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Realizar a identificação Das bicicletas e usuários.}                                                                                                                                       \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{B6B1B1}{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Garrafas conectadas}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Garrafas que possui NFC acoplado para fornecer informações do produto ao consumidor.}                                                                                                                                                                                                   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Colocando etiqueta NFC nas garrafas, assim, o consumidor consegue aproximar o smartphone da garrafa e obter informações sobre o produto.}                                                                                                                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Tesco no ReinoUnido, pela marcaMalibu.}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Consumidores de bebidas alcoólica.}                                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Realizar a interação de Produto e consumidor.}                                                                                                                                             \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{B6B1B1}}                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Garrafa de conhaque que possui na sua tampa a etiqueta NFC, para monitoramento da abertura da garrafas.}                                                                                                                                                                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Uma tag NFC, inserida no frasco, consegue detectar a abertura da garrafa e enviar uma mensagem de áudio que é recebida pelo servidor da empresa avisando sobre a ação .}                                                                                                 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}China}                                                                                      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Consumidores de conhaque.}                                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Combater a falsificação da bebida na China e melhorar o relacionamento Com os clientes}                                                                                                    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Gerenciamento de inspeções}}                 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Etiquetas que colaboram para verificar as condições de equipamentos de segurança e os serviços prestados  em seus nos equipamentos.}                                                                                                                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Inserindo tags NFC nos equipamentos de segurança, e através de um aplicativo consegue-se verificar as informações obtidas.}                                                                                                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Canadá}                                                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Pessoas e/ou empresas que necessitam monitorar equipamentos.}                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Monitorar equipamentos de Segurança.}                                                                                                                                                      \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: O código não compila, pois precisa de alguns pacotes para isto. Por favor, edite sua pergunta, fornecendo um código mínimo reproduzível.

Comment: Foi editada, esta tudo que precisa para compilar ela.. Obrigado!

Comment: Tem como colocar um print de como fica atualmente, descrevendo melhor o comportamento desejado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Centrar é o menor problema. Sua tabela é muito ampla para a sua página, ou seja, 3016,77289pt muito grande.

Seu `\textwidth` disponível no seu documento é de 345,0pt, então você precisaria de quase 10 páginas a mais para mostrar a tabela.

Eu fiz apenas a primeira linha removendo as `\multicolumn {1} {l |} {...}`.

A idéia é você preencher o restante deste código:

**Código**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{
%color, 
colortbl}                    
\usepackage{multirow, array}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption,multicol,booktabs,array}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
  \centering
  \caption{My caption}
  \label{my-label}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
  \begin{tabular}{lp{3.5cm}p{4.5cm}p{2.2cm}p{3cm}p{2cm}}
    \rowcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} 
    \textbf{Aplicação} & \textbf{O que é} & \textbf{Como} & \textbf{Onde} & \textbf{Pra quem} & \textbf{Objetivo} \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}  & Cartazes com etiqueta NFC embutidas, com informações armazenadas. & Espalhando os cartazes com a etiqueta, em diversos lugares da biblioteca. Os usuários necessitam apenas possuir um celular com NFC, e aproximar do cartaz, dessa forma, consegue realizar o download do livro. & Biblioteca virtual Na Áustria & Usuários que preferem ter o livro em seus Smartphone e/ou quando o livro não está disponível & Realizar downloads de  livros \\ \cline{2-6} 
  \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]